# What is the intended workflow for using the PlanningSceneValidityServer?

Tags: ros, environment-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand correctly, the **PlanningSceneValidityServer** provides a ROS service interface for performing state and trajectory validity checks (similar to how things were done back in diamondback).

I've been testing the fuerte implementation, and it seems to use whatever planning scene has been previously set (if any), by an external entity *not* part of the PlanningSceneValidityServer.

What was the original use case that inspired this node?. Before digging into the implementation, I was looking for something that would allow queries for the current robot state (and internally manage planning scene updates); this with the objective of simplifying these very common validity queries, because:

- The amount of boiler plate code to do the same thing has grown since electric.
- I'd rather not get/set the same planning scene multiple times from many (possibly remote) nodes, if they will all operate on the same scene.

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36233/what-is-the-intended-workflow-for-using-the-planningscenevalidityserver?/) by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The planning_scene_validity_server was put in place for users who still required a service call API for validity checks that were going to take a while - like checking the validity of a trajectory.  Allowing these calls in the environment_server made it worse at maintaining the state of the system as the validity checks require locking underlying data structures.  If you want to do validity checks from python using the validity server is your only real option.  By design it only allows for validity checking of the last scene that was syncned and not necessarily the latest scene in the environment server.

For getting the robot state, you can still make service calls to the environment_server.

For validity checks if you are writing in C++ I would suggest fetching the planning scene from the environment server and making the checks using the C++ API for CollisionModels - this will be vastly more efficient than making repeated calls to the validity server.

In terms of system design, you should only need to setting the planning scene if you expect there to be new objects in scene (a collision map, published objects).  If all you expect to happen is an updated robot state you can get that from the environment server and include it as part of the request you are making to an arm_navigation component like a planner or IK.

We realize that the system has gotten more complicated in some ways, but we believe the benefit in terms of efficiency, logging, and offline playback operation outweigh the complications.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-12-18**:
good explanation. according to my test, to get the validity of a specified state, making a call to the service provided by planning_scene_validity_server costs about 0.4ms, while using the C++ API for CollisionModels onlys needs about 0.2ms